# $C^\ast$ condition implies $B^\ast$ condition

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

By $C^\ast$ condition I understand $\|A^\ast A\|=\|A^\ast\|\|A\|$ and for $B^\ast$, $\|A^\ast A\|=\|A\|^2$.

I know these conditions are equivalent even NOT assuming the involution is isometric, but I would like to know who proved it and the name of the original article.

Thanks.